# How to update cell of a particular row in Google Sheets (based on Json data) using google apps script to create a New Jira issue and update sheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, jira-rest-api

How to update cell of a particular row in Google Sheets (based on Json data) using google apps script for Jira details, using the apps script to create Jira issue when new record created in excel which is working but how can i update the field value in Jira which i get in response.

```
// @ts-nocheck
function createIssue() {
console.log(arguments);

//Set the Jira Credentials
var username = "test"; // <=========================== Set your Username here
var password = "test"; // <=========================== Set your Password here
var UserCredentials = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password);

//var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("7492").getSheetByName("test");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var summary = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();

var IssueURL = "https://jira.test.com/rest/api/2/issue/"; // <=========================== Set your Jira URL here
var IssueData = {"fields":
{"project": { "key": "APPSCR" }, // Set the Project
"summary": summary, // Set the Summary
"description": Description, // Set the Description
"issuetype": {"name": "Task"}, // Set the Enhancement

}
};

// Call the Jira API
var payload = JSON.stringify(IssueData);

var headers = {"Accept":"application/json",
"Content-Type":"application/json",
"Authorization": UserCredentials,
"muteHttpExceptions": "True"
};

var options = {"method":"POST",
"headers": headers,
"payload" : payload
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(IssueURL, options);

// Parse the JSON response to use the Issue Key returned by the API in the email
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var response = dataAll.key
console.log(dataAll);
//
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(749202248).getRange(lastRow, 7).setValue(dataAll.key)
}
```

Looking a way in which can get response Jira id and update it in google sheet.
Jira response i get

```
{
    "id": "2573",
    "key": "APPSCR-355",
    "self": "https://jira.test.com/rest/api/2/issue/2573"
}
```

How can i get key having value of Jira id created and update it in sheet

[image: Jira]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. About `Looking a way in which can get response Jira id and update it in google sheet`, which do you want to put the value of `key` or `id` from `dataAll`? By the way, in your script, `sheet` is not declared. So, I think that an error occurs at `var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();`. From this situation, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this?

Comment: "key": "APPSCR-355" value which i get i want to update in G column. var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("7492").getSheetByName("test"); had uppercase name updated it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from `i get only Execution log 12:42:10 PM Notice Execution started 12:42:10 PM Info {}`, I couldn't understand your current situation. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly understand your current situation, I would like to think of a solution. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because my answer was not useful for your situation. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I would like to study more.

Comment: My flow is form submits data -> data added as record from microsoft forms to google sheet -> google action on form submit -> creates jira issue -> last step which fails i want the Jira issue details updated in sheet in last column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `` .setValue(`${dataAll.key}:  ${dataAll.value}`) ``.

Comment: Travelling let me try this once back and update here.